# Using CalculatedMembers in Aggregated tables with mondrian 2.4.2

Tags: mdx, mondrian, aggregates

I'm trying to set up custom aggregated tables in our mondrian data warehouse.
I defined the custom aggregated table like this:

```
<Table>
  <AggName name="..." ...>
    <AggFactCount ...></AggFactCount>
    <AggMeasure name="[Measures].[Example]" column="..."> </AggMeasureName>
  </AggName>
</Table>
```

As long as `[Measures].[Example]` points to a `<Measure name="Example" column="..." .../>` item it works fine.
When it points to a `<CalculatedMember name="Example" formula="..." ... />` then I get the following error message:

```
"Failed to find measure 'Example' for Cube 'ExampleCube'"
```

As far as I checked it online, this thing should be working for recent versions. We're using mondrian 2.4.2 which supports only Measures in AggregatedTables.

Is there any workaround, sg. like defining a cache-table?
Maybe is it enough to provide a configuration item?

Thanks,
Tamas

Comment: Errm, surely you mean 3.4.2? Just checking..

Comment: I mean 2.4.2, an ancient version, from 2007.

Comment: This is a *very* old version of Mondrian. It is possible that calculated members are not allowed in aggregation tables.

Comment: So seems like you should upgrade, or explain why you can't.  I can't believe such an old version works very well!

Comment: Sooner or later we will upgrade. Since we have a legacy application such changes don't go *too* quickly.